# Retrieve all the entries from a specified topic

Tags: django

I tried to fetch all the entries relating to topic `question`

```
In [17]: topic = Topic.objects.filter(text__icontains='question')
```

It throws errors when issuing the following command:

```
In [15]: questions = 
Topic.objects.filter(text__icontains='question').entry_set.all()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'entry_set'
```

So, the id should be retrieved firstly:

```
In [18]: [ i.id for i in topic]
Out[18]: [14]
In [19]: Topic.objects.get(pk=14).entry_set.all()
Out[19]: 
<QuerySet [<Entry: Why encapsulate button
```

Finally, get my result.

Nevertheless, it's awkwardly cumbersome, how to get it done elegantly?

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string representation of the model"""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform **filtering through the `topic` reference**:

```
Entry.objects.filter(topic__text__icontains='question')
```

This is a queryset that will contain *all* the **`Entry` instances** for which `topic` refers to a `Topic` instance for which the `text` attribute contains - when we ignore the case - the 'question'` substring.

We here thus use `topic__` to filter on attributes that belong to the corresponding topic. We can for example also filter on the primary key of the topic with:

```
Entry.objects.filter(topic__pk=14)
```

The double underscore (`__`) thus acts a bit similar to how in Python we typically use a dot (`.`) to access attributes: through a chain of double underscores we can obtain the attributes that are avaiable through a foreign key, and hence perform filtering, aggregations, etc. on it.

Another advantage of using this way of filtering over manually first obtaining the list of `pk`s of the `Topic`s is that this filtering is encoded in a *single* query (well for most database systems, of course there are no guarantees that this is possible in every possible database system, but popular ones like MySQL definitely support this). Although the query itself is more expensive than obtaining the primary keys of the topics. We here immediately obtain the `Entry` instances, whereas doing those queries yourself, will typically result in more queries, and thus a less efficient solution.